# One word for something that is distributed/handed out

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a single word which is essentially an item/component which can be distributed to people. I would have termed them as *distributables* (something that is distributable - a distributable), but I don't see the word ever being used as a noun.

For instance: Things like bookmarks and pamphlets are sometimes 'freebie-handouts' in a library. They are _____ (*distributables*?)

Comment: What's wrong with what you already have? Something that's handed out is a "handout": "printed information provided free of charge, especially to accompany a lecture or advertise something" (from ODO)

Comment: Do you specifically mean marketing-type items like your library examples, or are you thinking more broadly of anything that might be distributed, like snacks that get handed out at children's events and leaflets and "free hugs" from that one guy and so on?

Comment: ^Good question. I would like works for both I suppose, but the word I guess I need the most would pertain to your first description of what I'm looking for. Something that's given to people (Like USBs, etc) during a conference meeting? Yea so something like that..

Comment: _favors_ or _freebies_

Comment: giveaways or gratuities - I'd like candies please.

Comment: I've heard these giveaways called **[swag](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SWAG)**, but I don't see regular dictionaries defining swag thusly.

Comment: @Davo Yes, swag! I've heard it. And OED has it - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/swag (2/2.1). Urban Dictionary  has it, too - http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SWAG&amp=true&defid=2879826

Comment: I think it's rather depressing whenever I hear people insisting they *need* - or even *want* - a single word for something that's been getting along quite happily for a lot more than 100 years.

All that time, everyone else has been using *handouts* or *freebies* or *giveaways* or *goodie b…* oops! There was some fool about to use two words were one was demanded. Well, hush my mouth!

Comment: There are different words for this, depending on the kind of thing distributed or the purpose in distributing it or the relation to the agent distributing it and the receivers of it: *handout*, *swag*, *gift*, *prize*, *flyer*, *spam*, *propaganda*...

Comment: Yeah, "swag" is quite idiomatic in the US, if the stuff being distributed is supposedly of some monetary value.  "Handouts" otherwisew.

Answer (score 1):

In UK we often call a small paper bit of marketing material a "flyer", in US too?

Comment: Yes, in the US we would also call paper-based marketing materials *flyers*, but I believe the question has a rather broader idea for what is being handed out (it refers to "items", not just "paper").

Answer (score 0):

Consider the word **favors**. From Google:

> a small gift or souvenir (favor or favour, plural favors or favours)
>
> "good party favors include stickers, hair barrettes, or crayons"

In the United States favors are small remembrances of an event, often with the sponsor's name, such as a key chain, coffee mug, USB stick (as you mentioned), a pen, and so forth.  The term is also used for social events (weddings or dinners)--an item a person can take home and perhaps give to the kids.

Comment: This is used in the same sense in UK, too (but spelled 'favours'). Gifts/souvenirs  handed out at a conference would would more usually just be called 'freebies' here though - most likely as an adjective: 'freebie memory sticks'